# Was ist der Düsseldorfer Radschläger?

Tags: culture

I've heard a story about Düsseldorf and Düsseldorfer Radschläger was mentioned like the first assoсiation connected with this city.

Is it some kind of local tradition or a person?

Comment: It is a local culture of not fcompletely clear origin - one possibility being kids doing [cartwheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartwheel_%28gymnastics%29) out of happiness about winning the Battle of Worringen in 1288. If you can read enough German, try the [Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCsseldorfer_Radschl%C3%A4ger)  that doesn't have an English translation (yet).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes, I've seen the article but das ist mir nicht klar. Yet. Danke!

Comment: When I was in Düsseldorf in 1954, the kids used to do cartwheels on Königsallee. They did it for pocket money. I was there with the 1st Battalion Grenadier Guards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a local tradition: It is a kind of sport exercise for kids and part of some organised events. You can read some background here:

http://www.geschichtswerkstatt-duesseldorf.de/historischestextepublikationen/radschlaegerradschlagen/index.html .